# Typo3 template error t3lib_error_http_ServiceUnavailableException

Tags: typo3

I am currently experiencing a problem with a page template in typo3. It has worked fine for years but now whenever I use the template (for the homepage) I am getting this error. I have attempted to recreate the template, and have followed the instructions from the typo3 site to try and resolve it, but it isn't helping I keep getting this error whenever I use the page template, all other templates work. Anyone have any clue what is causing this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception

## 1294587218: No TypoScript template found! (More information)

t3lib_error_http_ServiceUnavailableException thrown in file
/www/websites/www.site.com/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_fe.php in line 2119.

2 tslib_fe::getConfigArray()

/www/websites/www.site.com/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php:
00291: // After this, we should have a valid config-array ready
00292: // ******************************************************
00293: $TSFE->getConfigArray();
00294:
00295: // ********************************

1 require("/www/websites/www.site.com/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php")

/www/websites/www.site.com/index.php:
00074: // ******************
00075:
00076: require (PATH_tslib.'index_ts.php');
00077:
00078: ?>

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a template record on your first page or the template above your page is setup to stop (thus is not inherited).
You need to create a new `TypoScript` template record in the `Template` or `List` module.